# String Conversion Issue with Get-DistributionGroup -Filter

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to filter a Get-DistributionGroup query by a group object ID, but the filter needs a string type. I don't know why, but the .ToString() method won't make it a string type according to my testing.

I'm sure the fix is simple, but attempts I know to typically work are not.

I hope I gave enough information since my problem is pretty simple. Any advice is appreciated.

```
$strGroupObjectID=$group.ObjectId.ToString()
$DL=Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {ExternalDirectoryObjectId -eq $strGroupObjectID}
```

Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Filter'. Cannot convert value "ExternalDirectoryObjectId -eq $strGroupObjectID" to type "System.String". Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an
object."

I tried the following but also met with the same failure.

```
[string]$strGroupObjectID=$group.ObjectId
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Get-DistributionGroup -Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps#-filter) help, you can use braces { } but only if the filter doesn't contain variables. See below for an example based on your code:

```
$group = Get-DistributionGroup -Identity 'ba757234-1038-43ec-b63d-23af03f4e2f3'
$strGroupObjectID = $group.ExternalDirectoryObjectId
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "ExternalDirectoryObjectId -eq '$strGroupObjectID'"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had further difficulties with the code, but I've worked around the issue, so the issue has past. I appreciate the help!